# Acess violation exception when trying to multiply matrixes by reference in c++

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, reference

I've been trying to create a function to multiply to 2 4x4 matrixes without having to copy one of them.
I did define the matrixes as one simple array column major ordered.

The result I came to is displayed on the function below. 
For some reason, everytime I try something like this:

```
matrix4 position = matrix4::identity();
position *= matrix4::identity();
```

I get something that translated to english should be like:

> Exception generated at 0x010004B6 in MFU-Core.exe: 0xC0000005: access violation when trying to write on 0x00E50000.

The exception points at this line.

```
elements[x + y * 4] = sum;
```

Am I missing something here? 
Thanks in advance!

Complete .cpp file:

```
    namespace mfu {  namespace maths {

        //Default constructor
        //Creates a 4x4 matrix filled with zeroes
        matrix4::matrix4()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4 * 4; i++)
                elements[i] = 0.0f;

        }

        matrix4::matrix4(float diagonal)
        {
            //Fills every element with 0
            for (int i = 0; i < 4 * 4; i++)
                elements[i] = 0.0f;

            //Replaces diagonal elements with diagonal
            elements[0 + 0 * 4] = diagonal;
            elements[1 + 1 * 4] = diagonal;
            elements[2 + 2 * 4] = diagonal;
            elements[3 + 3 * 4] = diagonal;
        }
        //Matrix format = mat[row + column x 4]
        matrix4& matrix4::multiply(const matrix4& other)
        {
            //All the rows
            for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++)
            {
                //All the columns
                for (int x = 0; y < 4; x++)
                {
                    float sum = 0.0f;
                    //All the elements
                    for (int e = 0; e < 4; e++)
                    {
                        sum += elements[x + e * 4] * other.elements[e + y * 4];
                    }
                    elements[x + y * 4] = sum;
                }

            }

            return *this;
        }

        matrix4 operator*(matrix4 left, const matrix4& right)
        {
            return left.multiply(right);

        }

        matrix4& matrix4::operator*=(const matrix4& other)
        {
            return multiply(other);
        }

}}
```

Complete header file:

```
namespace mfu { namespace maths {

struct matrix4
{
    float elements[4 * 4];
    matrix4();
    matrix4(float diagonal);

    static matrix4 identity();
    matrix4& multiply(const matrix4& other);
    friend matrix4 operator*(matrix4 left, const matrix4& right);
    matrix4& operator*=(const matrix4& other);
};
```

Comment: When the crash happens, what are the values of all involved variables? Do they look sane?

Comment: Typo: `for (int x = 0; y < 4; x++)` --> `for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)`

Comment: The elements vector and other.elements look fine but the variables sum look odd. Example:

elements[x+y*4] 1.98270866e+34 float

sum 1.98270866e+34 float

Comment: Right on point @RichardCritten. 
I kept looking for something difficult and in the end it was so simple... 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Couple notes: `std::array` would initialize data for you properly. The fact that you have to write expression `x + 4 * y` many times suggests it should be a function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your all columns, your loop never completes.  You should be testing `x` instead of `y`

```
//All the columns
for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
```